# jython manage.py runserver

Tags: java, django, jython, manage.py

Windows 7, 64bit
Jython 2.5.4rc1
Django 1.4.5
Django_jython-1.3.0

I am trying to follow the tutorial @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

worked fine and I now have my project structure. But then

```
jython manage.py runserver
```

generated a gigantic traceback error. Here are just excerpts from the start, middle and end.
It begins:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "manage.py", line 10, in (module)  
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line  
    utility.execute()  
...
```

continues:

```
...  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module  
    __import__(name)  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560  
        at org.python.objectweb.asm.CLassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
        at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
...
```

concludes:

```
...  
        at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:247)  
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)  

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 2560
```

This is definitely not what is to be expected. I can imagine that it is some kind of configuration problem, but I have no idea what.

Many thanks in advance for all assistance.

Here is the error in full:

```
e:\Django\Tutorials>dir    
 Datenträger in Laufwerk E: ist Executables  
 Volumeseriennummer: 82AF-DF4C  

 Verzeichnis von e:\Django\Tutorials  

16.03.2013  21:02    <DIR>          .  
16.03.2013  21:02    <DIR>          ..  
16.03.2013  21:02    <DIR>          mysite  
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes  
               3 Verzeichnis(se), 36.824.600.576 Bytes frei  

e:\Django\Tutorials>cd mysite  

e:\Django\Tutorials\mysite>jython manage.py runserver  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>  
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line  
    utility.execute()  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 382, in execute  
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command  
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command  
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands  
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands  
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner self._setup()  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _setup  
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 93, in __init__  
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 93, in __init__  
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)  
  File "E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module  
    __import__(name)  
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560  
        at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
        at org.python.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  
        at org.python.core.AnnotationReader.<init>(AnnotationReader.java:44)  
        at org.python.core.imp.readCode(imp.java:219)  
        at org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:185)  
        at org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:572)  
        at org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:478)  
        at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:718)  
        at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:827)  
        at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:917)  
        at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)  
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:387)  
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:391)  
        at django.utils.importlib$py.import_module$2(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py:36)  
        at django.utils.importlib$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:127)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)  
        at django.conf$py.__init__$8(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:135)  
        at django.conf$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:194)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:387)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:220)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:211)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)  
        at org.python.core.Deriveds.dispatch__init__(Deriveds.java:19)  
        at org.python.core.PyObjectDerived.dispatch__init__(PyObjectDerived.java:1057)  
        at org.python.core.PyType.type___call__(PyType.java:1565)  
        at org.python.core.PyType.__call__(PyType.java:1548)  
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:387)  
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:391)  
        at django.conf$py._setup$2(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:42)  
        at django.conf$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:134)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:109)  
        at django.utils.functional$py.inner$26(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py:185)  
        at django.utils.functional$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:301)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:141)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:327)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:124)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:115)  
        at org.python.core.Deriveds.__findattr_ex__(Deriveds.java:73)  
        at org.python.core.PyObjectDerived.__findattr_ex__(PyObjectDerived.java:983)  
        at org.python.core.PyObject.__getattr__(PyObject.java:923)  
        at django.core.management$py.get_commands$4(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:114)  
        at django.core.management$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:120)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:307)  
        at django.core.management$py.fetch_command$15(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:262)  
        at django.core.management$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:149)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:327)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:124)  
        at django.core.management$py.execute$19(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:382)  
        at django.core.management$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:134)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)  
        at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:109)  
        at django.core.management$py.execute_from_command_line$21(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py:443)  
        at django.core.management$py.call_function(E:\jython2.5.4rc1\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:134)  
        at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:317)  
        at org.python.pycode._pyx2.f$0(manage.py:10)  
        at org.python.pycode._pyx2.call_function(manage.py)  
        at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)  
        at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)  
        at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)  
        at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:235)  
        at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:247)  
        at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)  

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560
```

I look forward to any advice.

Comment: Can you paste in the full stacktrace if possible? Don't break it up.

Comment: Not a problem (I didn't want to create an enormous post unneccesarily):

Comment: What version of django are you using? I believe up to django 1.3 (maybe 1.4) is supported with DOJ.

Comment: The system info is at the top of the post. It is a first time installation of 'Jython 2.5.4rc1', 'Django 1.4.5' and 'Django_jython-1.3.0'.

Comment: Can you post the full contents of your settings.py file? Also, try downgrading to django 1.3 and see if it all begins working. django-jython 1.3.0 was built for django 1.3, and while it may support django 1.4, I can't find any guarantees anywhere other than the official django site. I've worked with django on jython, and it wasn't pleasant. If you can do straight django on python, you really should.

Comment: Jython was an experiment. I have now changed to Python2.7.3 and Django 1.5. I may re-visit this matter in the future but for now I shall take the simple way out.